# Proving that one infinite series is equal to another.

Tags: sequences-and-series

This is a question I've been messing with all day and still cannot figure out how to prove it. I have tried the ratio test which I assumes would the be the best idea but I need a little more of an idea of how to approach the problem. Here it is:

Prove that:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^{n}x^{n}}{n!} = {e^{2}} \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(x-1)^n}{n!}\right)^2$$

Comment: (x-1)^2 should all be divided by n!

Comment: @John Carpenter That's how it is at the moment.

Comment: It’s false: at $x=1$ the righthand side is $0$ and the lefthand side is not.

Comment: One could guess at what is intended. The current equation does not hold.

Comment: Well this is what my problem set says.

Comment: I have tried the ratio test for  both series and they fail both limits go to zero.

Comment: @JohnCarpenter Are you a native english speaker? If not, could you have mistranslated the problem?

Comment: Yes I am a native English speaker. No I am giving you the exact problem from my set.

Comment: There we go the power on the right should be raised to the nth.

Comment: @JohnCarpenter It's still not a true statement, check Brian's comment.

Comment: There we go I apologize for that. I had it right the first time in my latex editor and it was edited wrong. Both the nth power and the power of 2 were somehow taken out.

Comment: @JohnCarpenter Check Ishan's answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^n}{n!}$

So, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{2^nx^n}{n!}=e^{2x}$
and,
$e^2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(x-1)^n}{n!}=e^2e^{x-1}=e^{x+1}$  So this is not true for most values of $x$. If it was $e^2\Big(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(x-1)^{n}}{n!}\Big)^2$ instead, it would work.

Comment: +1 for your efforts. There's a typo in the second line, last exponent.

Comment: +1 Nice answer, but you really should correct that typo indicated by Git.

Comment: @Ishan I took the liberty of correcting the typo.

Comment: There's a typo in the last line too. The summation variable changes from $k$ to $n$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(x-1)^n}{n!}
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{x^k(-1)^{n-k}}{n!}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k(-1)^{n-k}}{k!(n-k)!}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{n=k}^\infty\frac{x^k(-1)^{n-k}}{k!(n-k)!}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^k(-1)^n}{k!\,n!}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\\
&=\frac1e\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}\right)^2
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}\frac{x^n}{n!}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{n=k}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}\frac{x^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}\frac{x^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{x^n}{n!}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2^nx^n}{n!}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Squaring $(1)$ and applying $(2)$ yields
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2^nx^n}{n!}=e^2\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(x-1)^n}{n!}\right)^2\tag{3}
$$